# radnumeric textbox allows ony 16 numbers

Tags: telerik, numeric-textbox

I have the following rad numeric textbox.

```
> <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="numTxtIMEI" runat="server"
> MaxLength="20" MinValue="0"   Visible="false"
> maxvalue="99999999999999999999" AutoCompleteType="Disabled">
> <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" /> <ClientEvents
> OnKeyPress="preventDecimalSeparator" /> </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Inspite of setting maxlength and maxvalue to allow 20 numbers into the textbox, it allows only 16numbers . when i type 17th number, it automatically turns to zero. what should i do to allow this numeric textbox to allow 20numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Telerik RadNumericTextBox control does not support maximum/minimum value more/less than +/- 2^46
Setting the MaxValue property  more than 2^46 may cause abnormalities in the RadNumericTextBox behavior."

Quoted from a Telerik forum posting.  I have linked it below.  It does give an option on how to do a larger number, but I have not tested that myself.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/input/change-max-value-of-radnumerictextbox.aspx